# Blood testing for chlamydia

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, dna-sequencing

I am working with the bacterium *Chlamydia trachomatis*.

The main test for this species is the naat test, which is based on amplification. But I would like to know how the bacteria affects the blood composition, and if there is a method of diagnosing it from the blood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blood antibody tests for *Chlamydia trachomatis* can be done, but they are far less reliable than amplification:

> According to our results, serologic testing for Chlamydia can exclude active infection of the lower genital tract with a high reliability (> or = 95%). However, detection of C. trachomatis can only be reliably achieved by nucleic acid amplification assays.

[Low correlation of serology with detection of Chlamydia trachomatis by ligase chain reaction and antigen EIA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10782395)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked your question about chlamydia and there is a way to check if someone has chlamydia from his blood. They take some blood and after they check if there is the Chlamydia bacteria. If they are not sure they simple do a NAAT test. The NAAT test will sure sow if there is chlamydia or something else.